# Sort a Map in Java is not working

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary

I am trying to sort a TreeMap (having Double as a value and Integer value as a key) using Comparator interface but it's not working.

```
// Create a tree map
        TreeMap tm = new TreeMap();
        // Put elements to the map
        tm.put(1, new Double(3434.34));
        tm.put(0, new Double(123.22));
        tm.put(4, new Double(1378.00));
        tm.put(2, new Double(99.22));
        tm.put(3, new Double(-19.08));
        List<Map.Entry> valueList = new ArrayList(tm.entrySet());

        // Collections.sort(valueList, new Sort());

        Collections.sort(valueList, new Sort());

        HashMap sortedMap = new HashMap();

        // Get an iterator
        Iterator<Map.Entry> i = valueList.iterator();

        // Display elements
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry object = i.next();
            sortedMap.put(object.getKey(), object.getValue());
        }
        List sortedList = new ArrayList(sortedMap.entrySet());
        Iterator<Map.Entry> iterator = sortedList.iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = iterator.next();
            System.out.println("Value " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
        }
```

The following is my Comparator class

```
public class Sort implements Comparator<Map.Entry> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Map.Entry o1, Map.Entry o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double valueOne = (Double) o1.getValue();
        double valueTwo = (Double) o2.getValue();

        int returnValue =
            valueOne > valueTwo ? -1 : (valueOne == valueTwo ? 0 : 1);

        return (valueOne > valueTwo ? -1 : (valueOne == valueTwo ? 0 : 1));
    }

}
```

But i am getting the following output

```
Value 123.22

Value 3434.34

Value 99.22

Value -19.08

Value 1378.0

Edited Part

public int compare(Map.Entry o1, Map.Entry o2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        double valueOne = ((Double) o1.getValue()).doubleValue();
        double valueTwo = ((Double) o2.getValue()).doubleValue();

        int returnValue =
            valueOne > valueTwo ? -1 : (valueOne == valueTwo ? 0 : 1);

        return (valueOne > valueTwo ? -1 : (valueOne == valueTwo ? 0 : 1));
    }
```

Comment: you should not compare Double values with `==` symbol, instead try comparing `>` and `<`, if no one return you a value, then return 0

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. I changed the value to double using doubleValue() method from Double Class , but it still is not getting sorted . Please see my Edited Part .

Comment: There is no `Map` implementation in the JDK that lets you sort by value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort a Map<Key, Value> on the values in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what others have already suggested, try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class SortDemo
{
  public class Sort implements Comparator<Map.Entry>
  {
    public int compare(Entry o1, Entry o2)
    {
      Double valueOne = (Double) o1.getValue();
      Double valueTwo = (Double) o2.getValue();
      return (int) Math.signum(valueOne.compareTo(valueTwo));
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new SortDemo().foo();
  }

  void foo()
  {
    TreeMap tm = new TreeMap();
    tm.put(1, new Double(3434.34));
    tm.put(0, new Double(123.22));
    tm.put(4, new Double(1378.00));
    tm.put(2, new Double(99.22));
    tm.put(3, new Double(-19.08));

    List<Map.Entry> valueList = new ArrayList(tm.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(valueList, new Sort());

    Iterator<Map.Entry> iterator = valueList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
      Map.Entry entry = iterator.next();
      System.out.println("Value: " + entry.getValue());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`HashMap` is intrinsically unordered.

Instead, you can create a `TreeMap` with your comparator in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

When you put them into the `HashMap` they will not retain their order, as a `HashMap` is not an ordered map.

Answer (score 1):

The `Comparator` works only your keys, not entries. You need a `Comparator<Integer>`, and pass in instance of this Comparator to the `TreeMap` constructor.

```
TreeMap<Integer,Double> tm = new TreeMap<Integer,Double>(myIntegerComparator);
```

In your example, the behavior you see is due to the `TreeMap` using `Integer`'s standard comparsion (this works because `Integer` is `Comparable<Integer>`).

(Btw, you should also read up on generics and use them in your collections classes, as well as any other parameterized class.)

Answer (score 0):

Using a HashMap for sorting will not work because its not a list.  You need to look into an ArrayList and the sort method.

```
ArrayList<double> arr = new ArrayList<double>();
sort(arr) //sort ascending
```